# Pseudo classes :visited, :hover, :active not working

Tags: css

CSS pseudo classess a:hover, a:visited, and a:active are not working

HTML:

```
<p> 
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="ChrisHorse.jpg" class="Horse"> My Photoshop Assignment #1       </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="puppies.html"> My puppies page </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="fish.html"> My Fish Page </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
a:hover {color:green;}
a:visited {color:red;}
a:active {color:black;}
```

Comment: Is your CSS in a separate file? Did you remember to <link> to that file?

Comment: What's not working?   Works fine for me here http://jsfiddle.net/GXt5B/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct order in your CSS should be:

```
a:link    { color: red }    /* unvisited links */
a:visited { color: blue }   /* visited links   */
a:hover   { color: yellow } /* user hovers     */
a:active  { color: lime }   /* active links    */
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code from [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqcwD/). It's work fine. Maybe you forgot to include your css file into your html file.

So, just include it from the following instruction :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming here that your problem is the `:hover`, the issue is that you're placing your `:hover` selector *before* your `:visited` selector, this means that once your link has been visited it will no longer have a hover style (as it will be overruled by the visited style). Simply change the order of your selectors:

```css
a:visited {color:red;}
a:hover {color:green;}
a:active {color:black;}
```

With this, when your link has been visited it will be red; when your link is hovered over it will be green, regardless of whether it has been visited or not; and when your link is activated it will be black.

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/xFDZR/)**.